# why using external c function in nasm breaks this code?

Tags: c, assembly, external, nasm

I've encountered a problem when using an external c function for debugging my nasm program.

```
%macro pint 1
  pushad
  push %1
  call printint
  popad
%endmacro

section .text
      extern printint
      global main
   main:
      mov eax, 3
      pint eax
      dec eax
      pint eax

      mov eax,1
      mov ebx,0
      int 0x80
```

while printint is defined like this:

```
 void printint(int a) { 
   printf("%d\n",a);
 }
```

the output I'm getting is 3 from the first print (as expected) and a random number from the 2nd print.
I was told that printf() might change cpu register values without restoring them, so i thought saving all registers on the stack before calling printf would prevent any registers from changing but apparently it doesn't.
can anyone explains why the weird output and how can i fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: You appear to be coding for Linux (based on how you terminate your program).  On this system, only the values in EAX, ECX, and EDX are clobbered by calls.  Also, it is better to return a value from `main` than to manually invoke the `_exit` system call: `mov eax,0;ret`.  And it's *probably* not a problem for your `printint` function, but in general, the stack pointer must always be divisible by 16 after the implicit push done by a `call` (so you should `sub eax,8` before pushing the argument in `printint`, and undo this afterward).  Frédéric's diagnosis of your actual problem is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printint()` is probably using the [cdecl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) calling convention. Under that convention, it's the caller's responsibility to remove the pushed parameters from the stack.

You should write:

```
%macro pint 1
    pushad
    push %1
    call printint
    add esp, 4  ; Clean pushed parameter.
    popad
%endmacro
```